# Setting localStorage with cart Products

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am implementing a e-commerce project in which i want store cartItems in local storage in react so it does not disappear after refresh.
Cart Items are set to local storage successfully but when i refresh it again set to empty array.
here is the code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart.cartItems));
}, [cart.cartItems])
useEffect(() => {
  let cartProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"));
  if(cartProducts){
    setCart({...cart,cartItems:[...cartProducts]});
  }
}, []) 


here is the state:
const [cart, setCart] = useState({
        cartItems: []
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On Each `refresh` of page, due to this stateAssignment

`const [cart, setCart] = useState({cartItems: []});` This `useEffect` is executed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart.cartItems));
}, [cart.cartItems])
```

And at that time `cart.cartItems` is `[]`. Hence it is set to `[]`.

You need to make sure that this `useEffect` should only run when there is a user-initiated change in `cart.cartItems`.

Comment: I used cart.cartItems as a dependency array so when then is a change in cartItems effect should run.

Comment: I think, `cart.cartItems` will also change when defaultValue is set for them, using `const [cart, setCart] = useState({cartItems: []});`

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

When both effects run when the component mounts, the initial render uses the empty array (`[]`) state to update localStorage. The second effect picks up the newly set empty array and reads it back into state.

## Solution

Use an initializer function for your state. Then the effect can persist cart to localStorage upon updates as usual.

```
const initializeState = () => ({
  cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [],
});

const [cart, setCart] = useState(initializeState());

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart.cartItems));
}, [cart.cartItems]);
```